# Button not appearing in tkinter. (python)

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am stating to develop a program in which you click a button with the text "open" on it, and it will bring up a file selection window using `filedialog.askopenfilename`, but the button won't appear, and it will automatically bring up the window without the button needing to be pressed. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()
root.title("Snake converter")
sim = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Snake files", "*.sim"),("Python Files", "*.py"),("All files", "*.*")))
openbutton = Button(root, text = "Open", width = 10, command = sim)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere in your code you're calling a geometry manager(`pack`, `grid`, `place` etc.) so your button isn't shown. Also `filedialog.askopenfilename` runs immediately even if it's assigned to an object. I am also unsure that you can call an object as button function. Try the following:

```
def sim():
    filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Snake files", "*.sim"),("Python Files", "*.py"),("All files", "*.*")))

openbutton = Button(root, text = "Open", width = 10, command=sim)

openbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

also your code should look like:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
root = Tk()
root.title("Snake converter")

def sim():
    filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Snake files", "*.sim"),("Python Files", "*.py"),("All files", "*.*")))

openbutton = Button(root, text = "Open", width = 10, command=sim)

openbutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I'd also check [frequent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter?sort=frequent) as a newcomer to tkinter.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe i forgot that!